# How to have facebook "Show more information about this article" on a published article?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wikipedia

Today I saw that a NYTimes.com article has some extra info on it - it says "Show more information about this article" and when clicked it opens a little window with Wikipedia descriptions and locations on the may where it was shared.

**How can I add it to my articles?**

[image]

The modal Window:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was curious about this too.  What [I found](https://www.recode.net/2017/10/5/16429786/facebook-fake-news-articles-news-feed-context) was FB adds the info button, in an effort to combat fake news. So, you can't add it to your posts.